# Meaning of "make some benjamins"

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

Big Smoke: Yeah, yeah, it's cool. Now, the way I see it is that we don't have a choice. Ain't nothing to feel bad about. You put a gun to a brother's head, brother's gonna do what he's told, no matter if he's a fool or a wise man. You don't want a bullet in the brain, but if you can make it work and **make some benjamins** while you at it, then that's cool.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Just to let you know, it's worthwhile to show what effort you put in to researching the topic about which you're asking. Did you try searching for the phrase in a search engine? What difficulty did you encounter? Questions which appear to be simply the result of laziness will often be downvoted. It's worth taking the tour and learning how to ask good questions which will help your status. (Also- if there's an acceptable answer, it's proper to "accept it" which benefits you as well as the answerer. All the best!

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy to just look up in a search engine of your choice. I searched 'benjamins meaning' and the first result was:

> Today's word is **Benjamins**. It is a noun meaning hundred dollar bill. The word comes from the name of a famous American whose face is showing on the hundred dollar bill. His name is Benjamin Franklin. Therefore, a Benjamin means a hundred dollars.

Also found in the [Merrian-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Benjamin):

> **Benjamin** noun (2)
>   Definition of Benjamin (Entry 2 of 3)
>   US slang
>   : a hundred dollar bill
>   Along the way, he amassed a small fortune, which he keeps in neat stacks of Benjamins in a closet by his bed.
>   — Ben Mezrich